# How to receive & process data when I subscribe to youtube api v3 push notification?

Tags: push-notification, youtube-api

According to this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

I can subscribe to a youtube channel & receive push notification for any new video.

My callback server is a php script which interprets POST/GET data:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['hub_challenge'])) {
  print $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}
else {
  $xml=file_get_contents("php://input");
  file_put_contents('endpoint.txt',$xml);
}
?>
```

But `$xml` is empty. In the docs it says:

> The YouTube Data API (v3) supports push notifications via
> PubSubHubbub, a server-to-server publish/subscribe protocol for
> Web-accessible resources. Notifications are pushed out to subscribers
> via HTTP webhooks, which is much more efficient than polling-based
> solutions.

But it does **not** specify how does it send the data....whether in **POST body** or in somewhere else.

So How do I get the atom feed in my script?

---

*EDIT:* I should probably ask a new question for this...but anyway....I tried this channel (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCATp8LNTjzjNlLxdArp0Myg); but when I try to subscribe it says **"restricted topic"** (I did not provide `token` as it is a public channel). Same for any other channel ID. Is something wrong with my callback server? I also tried runscope url as a callback server for testing. But it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others are having similar problems. Here is the issue log:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7138

and related StackOverflow question:

[Youtube API - Subscribing to Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611459/youtube-api-subscribing-to-push-notifications)

Unfortunately, no one seem to provide a solution although you can follow the issue and track any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it send data on the POST body . If you are using Express Nodejs add app.use(bodyParser.xml()) middleware to parse xml data